# Don't spin. You will hit people

Tags: grammar

He spun his hand on the hypermarket.

A woman near him was almost hit by his hand.

> "Don't spin. You will hit people."
>
> "Don't spin. You will hit others."

What should I use? Are they the same meaning?

Comment: I think that you mean he _swung_ his hand _at_ the hypermarket.

Comment: He spinned his hand in a circle.

Comment: @e12345678: *spin* is an irregular verb; past tense is *spun*.

Comment: So maybe *he spun around with his hand out* or *he swung his arm around*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both have the same meaning. However, a more idiomatic way of saying it would be,

> You might/could hit someone.